# Laravel - Get data from another table based on id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have next:

PublisherController.php

```
 public function show($name)
{

    $category = Publisher::with("publishers")->where('slug', $name)->first();
    if($category)
    {
        $ptitle = 'All '. $category->name . ' Albums';
        return View::make('album.list', array('data' => $category, 'ptitle' => $ptitle));
    }
}
```

And Publisher model:

```
    public function publishers()
{
    try{
        return $this->belongsToMany('Album',"publisher_id","id");
    }catch (Exception $ex){
        echo $ex->getMessage();

    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show all 'Album' records that have as slug the $name parameter.

The database is as follows:

```
albums
    id
    publisher_id
    name

publishers
    id
    slug
    name
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using the belongsToMany wrong. What should I be using instead?
Currently I'm getting a blank page, no errors showing which is also annoying.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename your relationship to `albums` and change the type:

```
// Publisher model
public function albums()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Album');
}
```

Then change the controller function to:

```
// rename $name to $slug for clarity.
public function show($slug)
{
    $publisher = Publisher::whereHas('albums', function ($q) use ($slug) {
        $q->where('name', $slug);
    })->where('slug', $slug)->first();

    if($publisher)
    {
        $ptitle = 'All '. $publisher->name . ' Albums';
        return View::make('album.list', array('data' => $publisher, 'ptitle' => $ptitle));
    }
}
```

Now you can access and loop over the `$publisher->albums` collection in your view file.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you! Any idea why am I getting a 404 for route Route::get('label/{name}', 'PublisherController@show');

Comment: What's the full request URL causing the 404?

Comment: https://domain[.]com/label/bla-bla  -where as bla-bla is a slug in the publishers table

Comment: Is `Route::get('label/{name}', 'PublisherController@show');` wrapped in any group(s)?

Comment: Check the request URL in your browser's web inspector and make sure thats matching. I don't see anything wrong with the url and route you've shown above.